# How can I create a Xylophone program using pygame mixer or pyaudio?

Tags: python, pygame, pyaudio, mixer

I want to create a Xylophone using pygame. I have created the image and split the image according to different notes. I need to upload sounds to those particular note sections of xylophone. Please help me with adding sounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used pyaudio and wave library(built in library) along with pygame to create xylophone.Pyaudio has advanced tools for audio processing as compared with pygame mixer.

You can refer my code here:

https://github.com/hackmaster0110/Xylophone/tree/master/PurePython

Comment: Checked out your python and cython codes. Can you give a comparison between them based on speed and efficiency?

Comment: I have used cython to improve the speed of the program.In cython we can statically declare the variable types.In the cython version I have compiled part of the program using cython which can be called by importing the .so file.

Comment: Because your xylophone didn't allow to repeat the same tone again without playing another one I have changed the code to `def synth(buffer,path,posx1,posx2,posy1,posy2):` and `if ((x>=93) and (x<=922)) and((y>=342) and (y<=715)):` in order to enable that. Now it is more fun to play it :) . Maybe you can update your code on github or provide it here (would be even better) so I can update it for you?